# Scala, ScalaTest - how to fix timeout problem using eventually?

Tags: scala, solr, scalatest

I have created a simple test code (using `ScalaTest`). The `find` searching in database using `Solr`.

```
implicit override val patienceConfig =
  PatienceConfig(timeout = scaled(Span(30, Seconds)), interval = scaled(Span(20, Seconds)))

for {
  ...
  saved <- service.save(...)
  result <- eventually {
    service.find(...)
  }
} yield result
```

But in 9/10 cases it ends with timeout. When I rewrite this code into:

```
implicit override val patienceConfig =
      PatienceConfig(timeout = scaled(Span(30, Seconds)))
    
    for {
      ...
      saved <- service.save(...)
      result <- eventually {
        Thread.sleep(20000)
        service.find(...)
      }
    } yield result
```

It works much better, but also I got timeouts sometimes (less than in first example). Do you know where the problem could be? I thought that something with `eventually` works different I thought, but I do not know what.
Also - is any way to make this code always run without timeouts? I prefer to use `eventually`, but would like to increase results without timeout.

I understand that it is possible that searching something in database could return timeouts, but I would like to have as most stable test as possible.

Comment: What is the return type of `service.save` and `service.find`? Are they `Future[T]`?

Comment: No, it is `ZIO[R, E, T]`

Comment: What does `service.find(...)` do when it can't find value? Does it throw some exception? Or return None? `eventually` returns the value returned by it's code block, but it does repeat the block only if it fails, i.e. throws exception.